# Microsoft Picture Manager wont print file names when printing multiple photos

Tags: printer, contacts

I have tried to follow the instructions for printing contact sheets with Microsoft Picture Manager.  Only problem I encounter is that no matter what subdirectory of files I choose from, or how many pix I choose, I cannot print the file names under each photo.  This is critical to my application, where I need to print out over 1,000 photos and I absolutely need the file name under each photo.  HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com). It is free and very powerful.

To print contact sheets, open the Thumbnails window, select the images, and go to File > Create contact sheet from selected files. You can specify the size of the paper and images, their spacing, etc. You can also specify text to print below each image. That text can include filename ($F) and size ($S) as the defaults. For multi-page printouts the default settings include a page number ($M).